# When do 64 bit pointer use only lower 32 bits on 64 bit machine?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, 32bit-64bit

**Background**:

I have the following simple code snippet:

```
Object * copied_object = get_result(original_object);
```

Where `get_result()` is something that returns a pointer (which should be a 64 pinter here on a 64 bit machine). I understand that, if I don't declare get_result() here, gcc will by default return int for that function, thus `result` will contain a truncated pointer (only 32 bits left) - I had a sig11 error because of this problem.

However, when I'm running my program, my error seems to be undeterministically appearing: I only hit it in the first time (I put this logic in a loop and every time I sent a signal from command line, the above code snippet will be execute; I had a signal handler so the sig11 didn't crash my program). After debugging I found that in the following times the pointers returned from the function itself are only using the lower 32 bits (even the pointers like `original_object` are also only use lower 32 bits) - thus the truncation didn't cause any problem.

**Questions**:

My question is, under what condition do we use only the lower 32 bits of a pointer in a 64 machine? What's the pattern of assigning the pointers?

Any help is appreciated, or some references are very welcomed.

Comment: i dont know of any reason you were go out of your way (or allow by omitting a correct procedure declaration) a pointer to be truncated. no good can come of it.

Comment: Thanks - of course I won't leave the pointer truncation in my code. I'm just trying to understand here why I'm not getting the same error every time, but only the first time - stably, every first time.

Comment: One possible reason: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization

Comment: But there can be any number of reasons. "Undefined behavior" could trigger all kinds of funny things, not all of them deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the operating system and how your program was linked. But user mode programs almost always run in the lower half of virtual memory. The kernel on the other hand is mapped into the upper half of the address space.

Also, most programs tend to be linked at a base address of 0x400000, so if they are not too big, most pointers will be within a 32-bit pointer. Many shared libraries on Linux will end up mapped higher.

Comment: but due to various reasons, like [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), the addresses used in a program does not neccessarily be fit in the lower 4GB

Answer (score 0):

Depends. You can correctly address the first 4 GiB of memory with an unsigned 32-bit integer. However, if the function has no prototype defined, the caller will expect it to return a *signed* integer, which can address 2 GiB of low memory and 2 GiB of high memory (assuming 2's complement signed int).
The question whether any particular object can be addressed is more complicated, as the C language doesn't mandate anything about addresses, except that you need to be able to calculate the address just past any valid object. Of course, this doesn't work if you're truncating pointers.
Given that modern OSs/loaders intentionally randomize the address space to combat security vulnerabilities, you should make absolutely sure to make your program 64-bit clean if you want to have it run in 64-bit mode. If you can't, stick to 32-bit mode (where applicable).